# Как при помощи json, обработать 2 submit, метод POST

Tags: php, jquery, json, post

Есть `html` форма с 2-мя `submit`:

```html
<form id="addCommentForm" method="POST" action="">
  <label for="name">Имя</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

  <label for="email">E-mail</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

  <label for="messageBody">Текст сообщения</label>
  <textarea name="messageBody" id="messageBody" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  <div class="buttons">
    <input type="submit" id="preview" value="Предворительный просмотр">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Отправить">
  </div>
</form>
```

Данные передаю в формате `json` в `php` скрипт, где валидацирую. Если есть ошибки вывожу такие сообщения, если всё верно на страницу добавляется комментарий и заносится информация в БД:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#addCommentForm').bind('submit', function() {
    $('.error').remove();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: "submit.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(msg) { //Данные отправлены успешно
        if (msg.success) {

          $(msg.html).hide().insertAfter('#addCommentContainer').slideDown("slow");

          $('#addCommentForm')[0].reset();
        } else {
          $.each(msg.errors, function(k, v) {
            $('label[for=' + k + ']').append('<span class="error">' + v + '</span>');
          });
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

На данном этапе всё работает, но мне нужно чтобы работало 2 кнопки. Первая для отправки, а вторая, **ВНИМАНИЕ**, для предварительного просмотра своего сообщения. Как ни крути, но всё равно надо на валидацию проверять. 
Какой `json` мне необходимо сформировать с одинаковыми проверками на валидацию, но на разные условия успеха?

Comment: Пробовали использовать разные имена пример для одного submit  name ставить другое а для другого другую, потом проверить командой isset($_POST['name']) какой submit установлен

Comment: Напишите функцию для проверки полей, для каждого input, к примеру, на keyup вешаете ajax к этой функции.. Или вообще используйте плагин jquery validate и не надо ничего писать самому (back только для проверки можно)

Comment: @Yanun, Всё дело в этом `$('#addCommentForm').bind('submit', function() {}` это ориентированно на тип, т.е submit, а не на id или value.

Comment: @InDevX, на сколько я знаю, самая лучшая проверка - это проверка на сервере. + я делаю упор на backend и мне необходимо валидация на php, та и сделал я её уже. И если я не ошибаюсь "мелкие проказники" могут отключать скрипты...

Comment: То есть ты хочешь при отправке формы не  было перезагрузки?

Comment: у тебя так не получиться нужны разные ориентиры, можешь через id проверить какой этот submit

Comment: @ Yanun, да разные ориентиры, и да так не получится, надо через id или value, но я пробовал, это не работает с моим уровнем знаний, вот и обратился сюда за реальной помощью

Comment: А если  фиаско, что пользователю будет показываться?

Comment: это ` $.each(msg.errors, function(k, v) {
            $('label[for=' + k + ']').append('<span class="error">' + v + '</span>');
          });` возвращается массив с параметрами ключ-значение, если, например, пользователь не ввёл имя добавляется класс `error` проверяется `label` сравнивается с ключом и добавляется надпись из значения: "Пожалуйста, введите имя."

Comment: если кто-то может предложить другой подход, решающий мою проблему, я готов им воспользоваться

Comment: Вы когда кому либо отвечаете пишите `@`, а не дубликаты плодите.

Comment: @doox911, вы по делу что-то сказать можете?

Comment: Содержание ответа скажите(то что в респонсе содержится)

Comment: @doox911:`$arr = $_POST;
$validates = Comment::validate($arr);
if ($validates) {
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO comment(name, email, messageBody) VALUES ('" . $arr['name'] . "', '" . $arr['email'] . "', '" . $arr['messageBody'] . "')");
    $arr['date'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
    $insertedComment = new Comment($arr);
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>1, 'html'=>$insertedComment->showComment()));
    die;
} else {
    echo '{"success":0,"errors":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
    die;
}
` https://github.com/SolodukhaAlex/Comments

Comment: @АлексейСолодуха Вы не поняли о чём я... На фронте валидация, которая при каждом keyup отправляет ajax на сервер с проверкой введённых данных. Вот что имел ввиду

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вариант, корорый избегает дублирования кода:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#submit-btn, #preview-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.error').remove();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: "submit.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $('#addCommentForm').serialize() + "&submit=" + id,
      success: function(msg) { //Данные отправлены успешно
        if (msg.success) {
          if (id == "submit-btn") {
            $(msg.html).hide().insertAfter('#addCommentContainer').slideDown("slow");
          } else {

          }
          $('#addCommentForm')[0].reset();
        } else {

          $.each(msg.errors, function(k, v) {
            $('label[for=' + k + ']').append('<span class="error">' + v + '</span>');
          });
        }
      }
    });

  });
});
```

В `data:` передаёте все значения из формы **+ id нажатой кнопки**(`+ "&submit=" + id`). И уже в своём php получаете значение id нажатой кнопки(`$_POST['submit']`) и спокойно работаете.
Этот вариант гораздо лаконичнее и избегает большого дублирования кода.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю почему мне не ответили, и вопрос вроде актуальный. Если кто-то столкнётся с такой же проблемой, вот решение:
в html :

```html
<form id="addCommentForm" method="POST" action="">
  <label for="name">Имя</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <label for="email">E-mail</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
  <label for="messageBody">Текст сообщения</label>
  <textarea name="messageBody" id="messageBody" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="submit" id="preview">Предворительный просмотр</button>
    <button type="submit" id="submit-btn">Отправить</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Вот что писать в скрипте:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#submit-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.error').remove();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: "submit.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $('#addCommentForm').serialize(),
      success: function(msg) { //Данные отправлены успешно
        if (msg.success) {} else {}
      }
    });
  });
  $('#preview').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.error').remove();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: "submit.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $('#addCommentForm').serialize(),
      success: function(msg) { //Данные отправлены успешно
        if (msg.success) {} else {}
      }
    });
  });
});
```